# Database Normalization and Design

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have the following two tables in the two different SQL Server Databases

Database Name: DB1
Table Name: A_TABLE

```
A_ID    A_NAME    A_LOCATION    A_AUX_ID
A1       John     New Jersey      101
A2      Abraham   New York        102
```

Database Name: DB2
Table Name: B_TABLE

```
B_ID    B_NAME     B_LOCATION
 B1     Joseph      Phoenix
 B2      Aman     Connecticut
```

My Requirement is to combine two tables and put it in a different database.

Database Name: DB_MAIN

Table Name: X_TABLE

```
X_ID    A_ID    B_ID   NAME       LOCATION        AUX_ID
 X1      A1      -     John       New Jersey       101
 X2      A2      -     Abraham    New York         102
 X3      -       B1    Joseph     Phoenix           -
 X4      -       B2    Aman       Connecticut       -
```

"-" corresponds to null

Is this is a better design? How well this works?
I feel this is not the way to do it. So, I am requesting some expert advice to proceed. Please guide.

Comment: If there is no further linking with old data and a_Id and b_id will always have different value than instead of taking 3 fields X_ID, A_ID and B_ID can take only one Id field like A_B_ID

Comment: Please elaborate on how you want to combine them, for what purposes, how it is used in contrast with how the original tables were used.

Answer (score 1):

You can design like this,

[image]

Stored ID's either from Table-A or Table-B in the same column like method-1.
Suppose if you want to distinguish ID's make use of a flag column like method-2.